# In Django, how to get child object that is connected by foreign key?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In Django, the following code works fine - event has a foreign key to group.

```
group = Group.objects.get(slug=cult_slug)
event = Event.objects.get(slug=event_slug)
```

The event that is returned above is what I need - it allows me to get field values from the event object.

I am trying to work out how to do effectively the same thing, but instead get the event object with a given slug via the cult object.

I have tried this, but it does not seem to return the same event object as in the top example:

```
event1 = cult.event_set.filter(slug=event_slug)
```

I also tried this but it also does not give me a working event object that I can get fields from:

```
event2 = Cult.objects.get(slug=cult_slug).event_set.filter(slug=event_slug)
```

Can anyone please suggest how I can get a child object via its parent, filtering on a specific field such as "slug"?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Cult.objects.filter(event__slug__icontains=event_slug)`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you back a queryset of events matching that slug.

```
event1 = cult.event_set.filter(slug=event_slug)
```

The following code will give you back an event object matching that slug.

```
event1 = cult.event_set.get(slug=event_slug)
```